Selecting the compensation components, RCOMP and CCOMP, in a DC-DC converter
We know that in that selecting the compensation components, RCOMP and CCOMP,  a DC-DC converter like the LM5155 is crucial for setting the control loop bandwidth and ensuring stable operation. These components are part of the compensation network, which is typically used to shape the loop response to achieve the desired performance, such as fast transient response and adequate phase margin.

I have been reviewing the LM5155 datasheet to understand the equations and formulas for selecting the compensation components, but I couldn't find any detailed guidance on this matter. Could you please assist me in locating this information or provide additional resources?

You are less than two months ahead from the release of my next practical manual on loop control! : ) The LM5155 hosts an OTA and you can have a look at this PPT I built for a type 3 compensation in a VM application. You have design equations for a type 2 or 3 and you can download my 130+ free ready-made templates here, and you have many compensated examples with an OTA for a type 2 or 3 version. Check this out!

@VerbalKint (Chris) has some amazing resources that will be well worth your time to explore.  But at a high level, you want to put two zeros around the double poles from the LC output filter, one pole to cancel the ESR zero, and a pole maybe at half the switching frequency to reduce noise.  Set the gain so that the loop crossover is maybe 1/10 the switching frequency and you should be in good shape. You can push the bandwidth higher if necessary, but if not 1/10 will typically allow good phase margin.

As kindly pointed out by Voltage Spike, the easiest and fastest way is to model the circuit in SIMPLIS using one of my templates. The part internals are well detailed and, for ac analysis, you need the feedback chain, including the various offsets and ramp generators. This is what I did below:

Once you have the circuit running and converging with POP, you extract the control-to-output transfer function of this boost converter. From the Bode plot, you read the magnitude and phase at the selected crossover frequency and enter the values in the right-side macro. The program will then automate the components calculations for the wanted crossover and phase margin:

The macro determines the worst-case RHP zero position and you should limit the crossover frequency below 20% of its value, 2 kHz in this example. The macro also automates the components values for this type 2 OTA-based compensator and there you go:

You can now run a transient load step (1-A step with a 1-A/µs slope) and check this is what you expected:

The circuit works with the free demo version Elements and I will soon upload it in my ready-made templates. The right side shows the values computed by SIMPLIS for compensating this converter. It is convenient as you can explore various compensation strategies and see immediately the effects on the loop gain and the transient response.

@Andromeda, hello, the file Boost CM with OTA LM5155 which runs on the SIMPLIS demo Elements in now available for download here.

Usually TI designs want you to run the regulator designs at specific frequencies and offer little documentation on how to compensate or change the values. Support and tools are the drawbacks of working with TI, and they expect designers to be fully fledged switched power engineers (I never went down that route in my courses). These are some options:
Check the webbench power designer to see if the LM5515 is there.
Check other flyback doc's for isolation (don't know if you are isolated or not) https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva866a/snva866a.pdf
Simulate the flyback yourself with Verbal Kints files and simetrix (I had to do this for a TI POE controller
Or trial and error by looking at simmilar voltages in the eval boards

Besides the analytical approach, values can be solved experimentally as well.  Sometimes this is your only recourse, when modulator gain/phase aren't documented at all.
Such testing should be done anyway, at least as a final step to confirm the design (i.e. without optimizing values).  Control parameters may vary with input or output conditions, datasheets might be misread or misunderstood, and sometimes datasheets are just flat out wrong!
First, take note of the error amplifier itself.  Voltage and current mode types are in common use:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For both cases, the R+C network (type 2 compensator) is easily identifiable.  In the voltage case, \$C_p R_f\$ gives the dominant pole time constant, and \$C_p R_z\$ the zero.  For current, \$C_p / g_m\$ and \$C_p R_z\$ respectively.  (Or frequency of the pole/zero, \$\frac{1}{2 \pi R C}\$.)
For example, the LM5155 appears to be gm type.  Given the large value of C13, evidently it has fairly high gm as well.  (I would say values closer to 100µS, or Rf ~ 10k, are more common, giving values in the low nF.  But whatever it is, it should be given in the datasheet; or when choosing Rf, consider input bias current and tolerable offset error, and perhaps node impedance/capacitance/noise susceptibility as well.)
For design purposes, it's generally safe to set an overly low dominant pole frequency, and adjust it upward (reduce Cp), while reducing the zero frequency (start with Rz small or zero, and increase gradually).  This is done while evaluating behavior with a frequency sweep or transient response.
Once you're close to optimal values, try smaller variations up and down, maybe try a little lead-lag, etc., and settle on final values.  Remember to test other supply and load conditions, particularly where operation changes (e.g. moving from CCM to DCM), and where modulator gain varies (usually Vin or Vout is a direct factor to it, and thus overall loop gain).
Value changes can be pretty loose, say 4-10x at first, 1.5-2x for final variations.
An initial dominant pole of say Fsw/1000 (or maybe Fc/100 for voltage-mode controls) ought to do.
Testing requires some measurement of the frequency response.  The dynamics can be probed most anywhere in the system, as far as seeing a squiggle after a step change, or a peak or valley in frequency response.
Testing at the output is simplest, and a switched resistor for load step testing is simplest of all.
For more control, or AC / small-signal testing, I would suggest wiring a MOSFET as a dependent current sink.  This can be as simple as a MOSFET with source resistor, and some gate bias, or an op-amp can be wrapped around it to get more stable (and calibrated) gain -- but beware, this is not a "gimme", rather it takes some optimization itself, needing adequate drive strength into the MOSFET gate, and isolation from the drain (feedback capacitance), to get good current-sink behavior to high frequencies (100s kHz).  A BJT circuit might also be worth consideration (higher gm, lower Ccb).
Note that the power supply itself needs to be biased into operation, to avoid, say, pulse-skipping behavior, or to test DCM and CCM conditions as applicable.  Typically a load step test might go between 50 and 100% of nominal output current, with a rise time of a few microseconds or less.  When using a switched resistor, simply wire one fixed resistor, then switch another resistor in parallel with it.
Very short edge rates, such as from mechanical contacts, can create annoying noise and false triggering; but it is nonetheless possible to do testing this way, i.e. by brushing a resistor against the output terminal and observing rising and falling edge transients.  Meme related.
Tuning
Generally, the dominant pole dominates control response, with the initial values giving a tall impedance peak at low frequency on the Bode plot, or an exaggerated and slow over/undershoot and recovery in step response.
As the dominant pole time constant shrinks down to around the output filter or modulator time constant, ringing or bouncing will become evident.  At this point, increase the zero resistance to flatten out the phase/overshoot and soften recovery, and so on.  (In terms of PID controls, the capacitor varies I, and the resistor, P.  A lead-lag compensator further introduces D.)
For simpler systems, this process will converge quickly.  This includes most current-mode controllers, where the modulator and inductor time constant is fast and simple, and the control zero will end up near that time constant,  effectively canceling out the pole, and then the dominant pole interacts with the output capacitor and load resistance to furnish an overall 2nd-order-dominant response.
Higher-order and non-minimum-phase systems may have more trouble:

SEPIC/Ćuk have extra poles/zeroes in the transfer function, which must be placed well above or below the control pole to avoid exciting the parasitic mode (and attendant increase in ripple and losses).
Boost/flyback have a RHP zero (at \$\omega_z = \frac{V_i}{I_L L}\$)[1] that necessitates a retarded control response.
Voltage-mode converters have to deal with the full LC filter (→180° phase shift above cutoff), so the control pole must be below cutoff, even with type 3 (lead-lag) compensation; a capacitor ESR zero can be introduced, but is a bit of a hack, often dependent on component parameters (e.g. an electrolytic; which ages, ESR goes up, stability goes out the window..).
For higher order (LCLC..) filters, feedback can be taken at the end for best DC regulation, but the excess phase of the long filter is obviously a problem: this can be addressed somewhat by AC-coupling feedback to a point earlier in the filter chain (i.e. from the first C), though the transfer function there is still fairly complicated.  A well-damped filter network (say using electrolytics and small ceramics, instead of large ceramics and/or polymers; or small enough Ls and large enough polymers so that the ESR still works out) helps a lot.

Not all systems can be tested in this way, at least in final form:

A class-D amplifier might be AC coupled at the input; the internal feedback node will need to be accessed to inject arbitrarily low frequencies, or a DC step.
A transformer-coupled RF (say, LF to MF) amplifier might have to be un-coupled, driving a load resistor or matching network instead.
A PFC stage, might have to be supplied with smoothed DC, or if the controller depends on a varying input, a modulated source might be required.
An average current-mode controller contains two loops: the inner current loop, and an outer voltage loop.  The inner loop must be compensated independently, say by setting up the system as a transconductance amplifier into a dummy load.  By tuning the inner loop to a dominant 1st or 2nd-order system, the outer loop can be compensated optimally against it, giving an overall 2nd to 3rd-order response.

Also beware of startup conditions, fault protection, and any other tweaks or quirks the controller might have (for example, frequency foldback at low Vfb).  If startup problems are present, or stable operation is complicated for other reasons (e.g. a self-powered flyback that browns itself out during excessive undershoot), you may have to probe into those causes, and solve them separately -- providing aux power externally, setting initial output conditions from a switched supply, clamping the feedback or gain node to avoid triggering faults, etc.
[1] SLUP084, The Right-Half-Plane Zero — A Simplified Explanation, Lloyd H. Dixon, Jr.; Unitrode/Texas Instruments

Hi Tim, the RHP zero in the boost or flyback (VM or CM) is not located at $\frac{F_{sw}}{2}$ but moves in relationship with the operating point. It is also there in DCM but at higher frequencies.

@VerbalKint Oh right, it's the CM pole there. I put in a reference instead, that should do.
